# Using UIImagePickerController with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

So I have a UINavigationController that pushes a UITableViewController from the rootViewController. From the UITableViewController, I want a UIImagePickerController to be pushed when I click a certain cell. How would I get the navigation controller to display the image picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
       UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       imagePicker.delegate = self;

       [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
       // don't release imagePicker here
    }
```

Then define [UIPickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) in your tableViewController implementation.

Comment: Note that the first will not work, because UIImagePickerController is itself a UINavigationController and cannot be embedded in another navigation controller.

Also, neither of these will work on the iPad. As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) you can only show a UIImagePickerController in a UIPopoverController or as a replacement of the current view.

Comment: I think the first should be removed, as it will cause an exception like shezi states, and that can be confusing to users reading this answer.